# How to use like , or and when with orderby in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Need to select by **'codevalue'** based on **like pattern** and then **order** them by some **specified order** . I have made the following query but sql throughs error msg

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHEN'.

Where am I making a mistake ?

```
select * from basevalue 
where codevalue like '01%' 
or codevalue like '02%' 
or codevalue like '03%' 
or codevalue like '04%' 
or codevalue like '05%' 
or codevalue like '00%' 
order by 
     WHEN codevalue like '03%' THEN 1
     WHEN codevalue like '04%' THEN 2
     WHEN codevalue like '05%' THEN 3
     WHEN codevalue like '00%' THEN 4
     WHEN codevalue like '01%' THEN 5
     WHEN codevalue like '02%' THEN 6
     END
```

Comment: You are missing the word `CASE`.  Should read `...ORDER BY CASE ... END`.

Comment: @destination-data thanks alot working fine ... cant believe made such a mistake

Answer (score 7):

It should work like this, you forgot `CASE` and `ELSE`:

```
select * from basevalue 
where codevalue like '01%' 
or codevalue like '02%' 
or codevalue like '03%' 
or codevalue like '04%' 
or codevalue like '05%' 
or codevalue like '00%' 
order by CASE
     WHEN codevalue like '03%' THEN 1
     WHEN codevalue like '04%' THEN 2
     WHEN codevalue like '05%' THEN 3
     WHEN codevalue like '00%' THEN 4
     WHEN codevalue like '01%' THEN 5
     ELSE 6
     END`
```

Comment: Not marking your answer as correct as @destination-data has already provided the answer , thanks for your concern and time

Comment: Oh, didn't see that. It's important that you found out what you were looking for

Comment: @stan.steve - Great that you solved the problem. But even if the answer was provided as a comment you should try to close the question. Read more about it on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) or [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253045/answerers-who-only-use-comments)